# CellStyle share the same heap address apache poi

Tags: java, apache-poi, heap-memory

When I am creating new cellstyles using `CellStyle` in apache POI, two style objects seem to share the same heap memory address.

How is it possible?

Please find the example below:

```
CellStyle style1 =  workbook.createCellStyle();
CellStyle style2 =  workbook.createCellStyle();
```

When I debugged the code, both `style1` and `style2` has the same memory address as `org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCellStyle@a1409f7c`

Could anyone please explain this weird behavior?

Thank you
Aswini J

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCellStyle@a1409f7c` you observe is not memory address nor anything like it but just toString() method of Object class.

Default implementation of toString() is `classname@hashcode`.

It is pretty clear that you instantiate 2 objects with default constructor so they have the same state. So default implementation of hashCode() will give the same hash code for those 2 different objects. They have the same class and hashcode, hence the result of `classname@hashcode` is same.